# Angular material table dynamic rows

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating a project using angular and material. In my project i want to add customised footer row in material table on click of button and delete that row on click of delete button.

Here is my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dshjiz-beqnrj?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html

Comment: What type of customized footer?

Comment: i have added in example...last row

Comment: What last row?? Is that footer you are talking about? And please explain *Customize* term

Comment: @PrashantPimpale : Yes footer row.. customized means last row having input box and checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to push data in datasource

```
this.dataSource.data.push({id: 1, name: 'test'})
```

There is [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-addrow-example)

Comment: i want to add only footer row

Answer (score 1):

You need to push data as mentioned by Armen. You also need to call renderRows() method of the table as per suggestion https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#1-write-your-mat-table-and-provide-data

Please check your updated [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dshjiz-njzxs6)

Same method can be implemented to delete the row. Just make sure the renderRows method calls everytime the table updates.